# Pandas: plot() without legend but getting TypeError

Tags: python, pandas, plotly

I'm getting a TypeError when setting legend=False but according to the documentation this shouldn't be a problem. What am I doing wrong?

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html

```
import pandas as pd
pd.options.plotting.backend = "plotly"

row = df.iloc[0]
row.plot(kind='bar', legend=False)

TypeError: bar() got an unexpected keyword argument 'legend'
```

The data in df.iloc[0] looks like this

```
RevolvingUtilizationOfUnsecuredLines    0.223647
age                                     0.071428
NumberOfTime30-59DaysPastDueNotWorse    1.130581
DebtRatio                               0.361630
MonthlyIncome                          -0.277019
NumberOfOpenCreditLinesAndLoans         0.025073
NumberOfTimes90DaysLate                -0.342467
NumberRealEstateLoansOrLines            0.728451
NumberOfTime60-89DaysPastDueNotWorse   -0.196677
NumberOfDependents                     -0.061967
MonthlyIncomePerPerson                 -0.029531
isRetired                               0.016656
Q1_Monthly_Income_True                  0.032911
Q3_Monthly_Income_True                 -0.000393
Q1_Revolving_True                       0.023684
Q3_Revolving_True                       0.273972
```

Comment: What version of pandas are you using?

Comment: I am using 1.3.5

Comment: What does the data in df.iloc[0] look like?....  What does `row.plot.bar(legend=False)` return?

Comment: I updated the question so you can see the data. row.plot.bar(legend=False) returns the same error. Plotting works fine without it

Comment: I can't duplicate your error here.

Comment: I can two things... update matplotlib and update pandas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are generating a **plotly** figure.  Hence change the layout of the return

```
pd.options.plotting.backend = "plotly"
df.iloc[1].plot(kind="bar").update_layout(showlegend=False)
```